# Getting the background of inner divs with one event handler

Tags: javascript

I have one click event handler. It handles the click of the outer div. Inside that outer div are multiple divs each with a different background style. I'd like to alert the background color of that specific div that was clicked style. Here's my code

```js
document.getElementById("buttonBox").onclick = function() {
  alert(this.target.backgroundColor);
}
```

```html
<div id='buttonBox'>
  Background:
  <div class='btns' style='background-color: orange'>A</div>
  <div class='btns' style='background-color: blue'>B</div>
  <div class='btns' style='background-color: green'>C</div>
  <div class='btns' style='background-color: black'>D</div>
  <div class='btns' style='background-color: yellow'>E</div>
</div>
```

Here's the link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ymcuxgpz/

Is there a way I can display the background of the inner div that was clicked with one click handler? For example, if I click the "A" div, the alert box will show "orange"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("buttonBox").onclick = function(e) {
   alert(e.target.style.backgroundColor);
}
```

You are close. This is possible through event delegation. Do a google search on event delegation and you will find a lot of material that covers this. This way you don't have to attach an event listener to each element.

Comment: Ahh, I was very close! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btns');

btns.forEach(function(btn,i){
  btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
   alert(this.style.backgroundColor);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id='buttonBox'>
  Background:
  <div class='btns' style='background-color: orange'>A</div>
  <div class='btns' style='background-color: blue'>B</div>
  <div class='btns' style='background-color: green'>C</div>
  <div class='btns' style='background-color: black'>D</div>
  <div class='btns' style='background-color: yellow'>E</div>
</div>
```